# Why byte is CLS compliant and sbyte not?

Tags: .net, byte, unsigned, signed, cls-compliant

Why unsigned byte is CLS compliant instead of the signed byte ?
All other unsigned types are are not CLS compliant, yet it is just the opposite on bytes.

```
sbyte x = 1; //NOT CLS Compliant
byte y = 1; //CLS Compliant
```

Comment: Because CLS compliance defined that way- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/12a7a7h3(v=vs.100).aspx... Not sure what kind of help you are looking from SO with this.

Comment: It is a subjective thing no one except Microsoft can tell more. But one fact is that some languages simply do not support unsigned types.